# I deleted a page, but it still appears on the site. How can I delete this page?

Tags: content-editor, publishing, workflow, versions, caching

Through Content Editor I deleted a page, after that, I published the folder where it was contained. But even deleted the page keeps appearing on the site and I do not know how to remove. The strange thing is that the page that I deleted appears in Recycle Bin.

I'm using Sitecore 8.0 version.

Comment: Do you use any caching? Try switching to `web` database from Sitecore Desktop and see if your page is there. And are you sure you checked "publish subitems" when publishing parent folder?

Comment: In Browser Cache Settings, the option no cache and no store are checked. I delete this page yesterday. How can I see web database from Sitecore Desktop? I think that I don't have access in this section.

Comment: Open `.../sitecore/shell/ in the browser and on the bottom right cornet of the screen there is a button to switch database. Make sure you switch back to `master` when you're done

Comment: I got deleted the page, thank you so much! The option "publish subitems" didn't checked when publishing parent folder. Sorry, but I forgot verify this.

Comment: Comments converted into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure to check "publish subitems" when publishing parent folder.

To verify if the item was removed from the `web` database, switch to `web` database from Sitecore Desktop and see if your page is there. Open `.../sitecore/shell/` in the browser and on the bottom right corner of the screen there is a button to switch database. Switch back to `master` database when you're done.